# OpenLDAP Access Levels: What is "search" without "read" good for? What does "manage" provide which "write" doesn't?

Tags: openldap

I try to understand the different access level which OpenLDAP provides, see [OpenLDAP 2.6 Guide: Access Control - The access to grant](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/access-control.html#The%20access%20to%20grant).

While access levels like `write` are clear just by their name, IMHO, the documentation falls short on giving a precise definition how some levels differ from other. Or may be some divisive examples which shows how the different levels are separated.

##### Difference between `search` and `read`

The documentation says access level `search` is required to apply search filters, access level `read` is required to read the result of a search filter. What is `search` alone good for then? What would be an example in which a client applies a search filter, but doesn't need a result?

#### Difference between `write` and `manage`

The documentation says access level `write` is required to modify, level `manage` to manage. (The latter is a rather tautological definition.) What does `manage` provide which `write` doesn't?

In particular, this question bother me, because all settings which control the behaviour of OpenLDAP are stored as objects and their values inside the DIT itself. Hence, if one wants to manage an OpenLDAP setting one has to modify (aka write) the respective object/value.

Answer (score 1):

For the `search` section, it will tell you the number of results.

If you have a binary attribute (for example, invited people) you can know how many off them are truly invited, and which ones are not. Yet you would not know which ones are the ones invited. Unless you have `read` permission.

For the difference between `write` and `m̀anage`, it is a little bit more complicated. `manage` let you write even if you are not supposed to do it like that. One easy example is to write passwords that do not respect password policy (not long enough or without numbers and special characters...). The uses are not quite common, hence most accounts will only need `write`. Nevertheless, `rootdn` has `manage` permission, as will be expected.

Hope it helps :)